# Is there any selective benefit in caching string instead of an object in Java? Does it differ in Python?

Tags: performance, python, java, caching

I was once suggested by a dear colleague of mine, that it is preferable to serialize objects (say maps, JsonObjects etc.) into strings and store them in caches instead of the objects themselves, for less active caches. The reason he provided was that since all these objects come with their own methods and whatnot, it increases the footprint of the object. I understand strings too come with their own methods, but not huge. He suggested it was still a preferable choice, even with the additional cost of parsing the strings and converting them back to the original objects during retrieval.

Is there any water in these claims? Or is there any other suggestions around the same?

Answer (score 0):

Methods and such are loaded once per class. They don't take additional memory no matter how many instances of the class you create.

In Java, the footprint of the following object is 16 bytes:

```
class EmptyObject {
}
```

If your object holds references, every reference is another 8 bytes. So for instance, the footprint of the following object is 80 bytes:

- 16 bytes for instance definition
- 8 bytes for the array reference
- 16 bytes in the actual array

```
class AnotherObject {
  byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
}
```

Now suppose we cache our objects, and suppose the cache is a glorified `HashMap`, as it essentially stores a key-value pair.

Consider the following class. With empty strings, it takes 32 bytes:

```
class Person {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
}
```

Say your keys are 16 byte-long strings; 32-byte objects.

If you put a `Person` into cache, it takes

- 8 bytes for key reference
- 32 bytes for key
- 8 bytes for value reference
- 32 bytes for value

**Total: 80 bytes**

Now, suppose we store strings individually. For each key:

- 8 bytes for key reference
- 32 bytes for key
- 8 bytes for value reference
- 16 bytes for value (empty string)

Multiply x2. **Total: 128 bytes**

---

Only in this case it will make sense to store the strings instead of objects:

```
class StringWrapper
  // the only field in the class
  String string;
}
```

but even then, savings are nominal.

TL;DR: it's a micro-optimization that isn't worth it most of the time

Comment: Ah, I think my question did not exactly come out the way I intended to come. What I meant is instead of storing Objects, is it better if I serialize the object to a string, and then store. And convert to the object from strong post retrieval.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Much appreciated.

Comment: Well, in actual JVM its a bit more complicated, and "AnotherObject" does not always need extra 8 bytes for array reference. As there is enough unused space in these 16 bytes taken by any class reference to fit that one field. And in other case some space might be wasted because padding. Like adding a single byte field to AnotherObject will consume 8 more bytes, and then adding another byte will not affect the size. And all of that depends on used flags and jvm implementation.